# Why does 'app' go as a parameter for module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my routes file, I export all code and import it at my index.js. What's the purpose of inserting 'app' as a parameter in my export statement?

```
module.exports = (app) => {
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some of the other code here too? It would be easier to understand your question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is a [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that accepts one argument.

This module is exporting a default function which can be imported like this

```
var test = require('./whatever-file');
```

and now `test` is a function.

```
test('a string argument')
```

Obviously with the little that is posted we can't infer what type `app` is supposed to be. So, you will need to adjust according to whatever is needed.